# Angularjs uib-typeahead object in array

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I am trying to implement typeahead by searching through an array of objects. How do i do so? I only know how to search through an array but not an array of object

Array of object

[image]

HTML:

```
   <input type="text" class="searchFeature" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && 
   searchFunction()" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="value for value in 
   allTheme | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7" placeholder="Start your search here.">
```

The result i am getting :

[image]

PS: Is it possible to get just the "THEMENAME" and "Category" object and filter it in my typeahead search?

Comment: I don't see how you can show both parameters you are searching for, but with one,  you need to select its key: `value.THEMENAME for value in allTheme`. If you want to search by some specific key, write a custom filter for that

Answer (score 0):

try

> uib-typeahead="value.THEMENAME for value in 
>      allTheme | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7"